# Executing JavaScript Within a User Control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET user control that will load a specified RSS feed given the feed's URL. Ideally I wanted to keep everything wrapped up in the user control so that it can simply be put into a page, set the feed URL and be done with it. I'm using jQuery AJAX to keep the page more responsive. Here's the barest of skeletons I've started with:

Inside an ASP.NET Web Form:

```
<div>
    <ResellerViewControls:RssFeedListAjax FeedUrl="http://www.samplelist.com/rss/" />
</div>
```

The user control's innards:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="RssFeedListAjax" %>

<script runat="server">
    public string FeedUrl { get; set; } 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Loading...');
        parseRSS('<%= FeedUrl %>', showResult);
    })();

    function parseRSS(url, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(data.responseData.feed);
                } else {
                    throw Error("No callback function provided");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function showResult(data) {
        $('#RssFeedList').innerText = data;
    }
</script>

<div id="RssFeedList">
</div>
```

The web form's master page has references to all the necessary jQuery stuff. When browsing the page using FireFox developer tools, I can't find the actual user control's javascript anywhere. I guess it's not getting rendered.

Any assistance in getting this or something similar to work is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. After looking through it again, I realized I was omitting a critical thing: the 'runat=server' attribute on the user control. That did the trick.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind. You might want to render the javascript thats in your user control using [`ClientScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) instead of embedding the javascript in the control. The reason is because if you have more than one user control on a page, the javascript will conflict.

Comment: @icemanind That's actually a good idea. I will do that. Thanks.